# highcharts error "undefined is not an object" when clicking a chart column in Safari

Tags: highcharts

I have a highchart column chart that gives an error when clicking a column.
This occurs only in Safari on Max OS X, not in other browsers (including iPad)

The error is:

> TypeError: 'undefined'is not an object (evaluating 'u.isList')

Can anyone tell me what happens? I'm not easily able to build a reproduceable jsFiddle...

Comment: Could you supply any piece of code? How we can reproduce this issue? Which version of Safari / Macosx do you use?

Comment: Thanks guys for your replies.
When trying to build a reproduceable fiddle, I found that the error was caused by own code, not by Highcharts... Sorry!